# Aux routes not working while nested in main route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am having trouble getting an aux route to work as a child of my primary route

I basically have two routes for the main outlet - auth and a second one that houses the entire application.

Inside that application route (RootComponent) I have another primary router outlet that houses the main application views (DashboardComponent and TasksComponent) and an aux route outlet for a sidebar that should render the secondary views (BacklogComponent and ProjectsComponent). I cant seem to get the secondary routes to activate.

If I move the aux route to be a sibling of the first outlet in app.component.ts it works but that would obviously mean the route sits outside of my main app view which is RootComponent

I have also tried navigating in the URL bar to both /dashboard(sidebar:backlog) and /(dashboard//sidebar:backlog)

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent},
  {
    path: '', component: RootComponent, children: [
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'tasks', component: TasksComponent},
      {path: 'backlog', component: BacklogComponent, outlet: 'sidebar'},
      {path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent, outlet: 'sidebar'}
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

app.component.html (should render first level. Ie. AuthComponent or RootComponent)

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">dashboard</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/tasks']">tasks</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sidebar: ['backlog'] } }]">backlog</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sidebar: ['projects'] } }]">projects</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sidebar: [] } }]">close</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

root.component.html (houses the main application view)

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
```

When I try to route to Backlog using `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sidebar: ['backlog'] } }]"` I get: `core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'backlog'`